# Decision surface in linear classification

Tags: geometry, statistics, machine-learning

I have several question regarding the following definition of a linear hyperplane for classification:

We define our classifier $F$ as follows:

$$F(x) = \text{sign}(\langle w,x\rangle +b) \in \{1,-1\}$$

where

$$\text{sign}(z) = \begin{cases} 1&z \geq 0\\
-1&z < 0 \end{cases}$$

> My questions:
>
> 1. How comes the threshold can be assumed to be $0$? Do we have to set constraints on weight vector $w$ and bias $b$ s.t. this is fulfilled? I don't see why for different problem sets it would not be any number $\in R$.
> 2. As far as I know, $\langle w,x\rangle+b =0$ defines a plane only if $w$ is a normal vector...again, how comes that $w$ is normal? Is this again a constraint we set during optimization?
> 3. In our lecture notes, it is mentioned that $|\langle w,x\rangle+b|$ is the distance of the vector $x$ from the hyperplane $\langle w,x\rangle+b = 0$. How so?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Because of the bias term. The $w$ forms the orientation of the hyperplane (it determines the normal vector to the plane), while the bias $b$ forms the "position" of the plane. Consider a simple case in 1D: every point greater than 10 is +1; others are -1. Then the bias simply moves the threshold to 10. In every (linearly separable) case, one can let the threshold be 0, and let the $b$ make up for it. (Alternatively, one can change the threshold and force $b$ to be 0, but it would be the same).
2. It's the other way around; look at the definition of [hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane). Any equation $\vec{w}\cdot\vec{x}={b}$ forms a hyperplane. The classical form for a [plane](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html) is $\vec{n}\cdot(\vec{x}-\vec{b})=0$, where $\vec{n}$ is the normal to the plane and $\vec{b}$ is the intercept. So $w$ determines the normal, by definition.
3. This only seems to be correct if $w$ is a unit vector. The unsigned distance from a point $p$ to a plane $w\cdot x+b=0$ is (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424125/shortest-distance-from-a-point-to-a-plane)):
   $$
   d(p) = \frac{|w\cdot p + b|}{||w||_2}
   $$
   This is not assumed in general (though it sometimes is). See [here](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~piyush/teaching/8-9-print.pdf) for instance.

Also, consider looking at descriptions of the [perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron), which is what you are concerned with.

Comment: thx for the good explanations: 1. Is there then a constraint of some form on b during optimization? 2. Ok understand that each equation w*x = b defines a (hyper)plance, but then again, w is not necessarily a normal (though the n*(x-b) = 0 obviously is, due to the scalarproduct being 0)..? Can we rescale x somehow s.t. w becomes a normal?

Comment: @Pegah (1) Depends on the algorithm used to determine them. For a perceptron, no. For a [linear SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Linear_SVM), yes, there are constraints involving $b$. (2) $w$ is the normal. (Look at the picture at the linear svm link.) Let $\vec{n}\cdot(x-x_0)=0$, then $\vec{n}\cdot x = \vec{n}\cdot x_0 = b $ so define $w:=\vec{n}$ and we get $w\cdot x = b$. I dont like to call it that because it is not necessarily a unit normal though.