# Distance from a point to a plane (with matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

Let $W$ be some inner product space over $\mathbb{R}^2$ where the inner product $\langle\,A,B\rangle=tr(AB^t)$ ($B^t$ in this case is $B$ transposed).

$w_1=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{smallmatrix}\big)$, $w_2=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\big)$
and also $W=span\{w1,w2\}$,

Calculate the distance of
$v=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}4&0\\4&4\end{smallmatrix}\big)$
from $W$.

I know that I need to first find the projection of $v$ onto $W$, and from there it's smooth sailing. But, I don't know how to represent W. [In similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424125/shortest-distance-from-a-point-to-a-plane) we usually want to find the Normal of the plane, and project $v$ onto it. However in this case, I don't know how to find the normal of a span of matrices. We'd have to find a vector $U$ that is orthogonal to both $w_1,w_2$. I tried to find the orthonormal basis (using Gram–Schmidt) $B=(e_1,e_2)$, and say that $U=e_1+e_2$, but my $U$ came out to be equal to $w_2$ which didn't make much sense.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: A vector space of $2\times 2$ matrices is just a (subspace of) 4-dimensional vector space. Reshape the elements of $W$ to columns, keep track of what your inner product looks like in that form, and you're good to go with your standard method.

Comment: That is essentially what I did. It seems that either I don't know the standard method well enough, or something else is wrong with my approach.

Comment: Note: We want an orthonormal basis of $W$ itself, not of the space perpendicular to $W$. Does that help?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I just noticed that $w_1$ and $w_2$ are not orthonormal. So yeah, it does help! I also noticed another mistake: $U=⟨v,e_1⟩e_1 +⟨v,e_2⟩e_2$. Now it comes out right!